# Did the mist only affect Allomancers?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

In *The Hero of Ages*, it is revealed that

> the mists, which seemed to want to kill people, were actually just trying to make them Snap.

**So, if they were trying to do this, were they only affecting Allomancers, or were they indiscriminately doing this to random people?**

Answer (score 3):

Everyone affected by the mists’ snapping had allomantic potential.

In the annotations for *The Hero of Ages* Chapter 49 Part 2, Brandon Sanderson says:

> Noblemen, despite what Spook says in this chapter, are not immune to the mistsickness. The rumor Spook is referencing does have merit, however. You see, since the mists are Snapping people **and awakening the Allomantic potential within them**, it will affect far fewer noblemen than skaa. Why? Because a lot of the noblemen have already Snapped. They were beaten as children to bring out the powers.
>
> However, that won’t stop all of them from being affected by the mistsickness, because **the mistsickness is also awakening Allomantic potential that would otherwise be too subtle to be brought out**. Pretend there’s a sliding scale of Allomantic potential. 100% means you’re an Allomancer—in this series, only two people have hit 100%—Vin and Elend. Buried within a lot of people, however, is enough of a touch of Preservation’s power to hit, say, 50% on the relative scale of Allomantic power. These people, when beaten and made to pass through something traumatic, awaken to their Allomantic abilities.
>
> There are a lot of people out there, however, with something more like 20% to 30%. **These are the people the mists are Snapping—since the mists are, themselves, partially the power of Preservation, they can touch people and increase their Allomantic potential slightly and then bring it to the forefront.**

Emphasis mine. [source](https://brandonsanderson.com/annotation-mistborn-3-chapter-forty-nine-part-2/) (you will probably have to click the "show spoilers" button to see the relevant quotes)

Basically, it was able to snap people who otherwise would not have been able to snap through regular circumstance, awakening the weak allomantic powers in their bloodlines.

You can note that unlike the other answer, this suggests that nobles are *not* immune to the snapping; but are just statistically less likely to benefit. They have attempted snappings at youth, and the bloodlines are generally strong enough that such a snapping unlocks their power, so it is much less likely for them to have a hidden potential that the mists can tap.

Comment: In the thing about percentages, is he saying that Zane is somehow weaker than Vin?

Comment: It was specifically to snap Mistings would could burn Atium, since there would be no way to find those, given how rare and valuable Atium was. Also, the inquisitors have been hunting Atium Mistings in secret. https://mistborn.fandom.com/wiki/Atium

Comment: @Stormblessed I don’t quite remember anything suggesting otherwise (Vin was a pretty strong Mistborn).  I’m not sure if I fully understand Sanderson on that point either though, since AFAIK Elend was really “100%” due to Lerasium and Vin wasn’t quite that strong.

Comment: @Amarth That link seems to imply that only _some_ of the people snapped by the mist are seers.

Comment: Iirc those who were particularly ill like Demoux were potentially the Mistborn, wheras Seer refers to someone who can only burn Atium, like Yomen.

Comment: @Amarth Demoux was only a seer too.  The clue was that the seer mistings had worse snapping.  It was like 1 in every 16 snapped, and one in every 16 in those had it bad and ended up being seers.

Comment: It might be so. Anyway, the whole purpose of the mist Snapping people is to bring out Atium Mistings. If a side-effect of that is bringing out other Allomancers, I can't say and I'm not sure if the book explained it, since it isn't very relevant to the story.

Comment: @Amarth It was important to how they figured it out.  16% of the people the mists encountered got "sick".  1/16th of those got sick significantly longer, for 16 days.  Everything I can find suggests that the mists were snapping everyone, not just the seers who were sick longest.  https://coppermind.net/wiki/Mistfallen

Answer (score 0):

Both, kind of? Anyone who got sick became an Allomancer. But the thing was that the Mists only affected 16% of those exposed to it, and it didn't affect nobles at all - because all the nobles already Snapped. Thing is, it turned 16% of the skaa into Allomancers, and given that Kelsier mentions that Allomancers in skaa can only be found in about 10,000 mixed breeds. (Going back five generations is considered mixed breed, here. Ham, I think, is second generation.) So everyone who got affected became an Allomancer (or died, but they possibly might have also been Allomancers too). 16% of that 16% became Seers (I think? Memories a bit hazy on that point) by getting sick for a few weeks. So, the Mists were indiscriminately targeting people, just not people who were already Snapped, and anyone they targeted turned into Allomancers.